# How to use screen inside of an LXC container

Tags: gnu-screen, lxc

I am using Proxmox 7.0 to run an LXC container with Debian 11 as guest. When connecting via ssh to the guest, I can install and run `screen` as usual. I can detach and re-attach as usual. But if I disconnect the SSH connection and reconnect, my screen session is gone. Any idea why?

I used another ssh connection to look via `htop` at the processes and saw, that screen is terminated immediatley after I close the ssh session.

Comment: Is systemd in your container configured to kill user processes on logout?  That should be disabled by default on Debian, but check /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Comment: it only contains `[Login]` - every other line is commented out